# PostgreSQL python trigger getting strange error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, database-trigger

PostgreSQL V10. Python V3.6. Code is in 'AFTER INSERT' trigger.

First the error:

```
ERROR: spiexceptions.ExternalRoutineException: NameError: name 'ts' is not defined
  Where: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "trade_buy_after", line 30, in <module>
cashRslt[0]['symbol'], cashRslt[0]['price'], 0.00, tbRow['amount'], const['SW_OUT'], note]);
PL/Python function "trade_buy_after"
```

Seems straight forward, but I cannot find anything called 'ts'. I have looked in all the relevant code that may be executed by the insert.

Here is the pertinent part of the function. the error is on the 'sellRslt =' line:

```
  tbRow = TD['new'];

  _logger.debug(tbRow);

  if tbRow['source_revenue_id'] == None:
    _logger.debug("tb after: rev == None");
    note = "Sweep-Out for purchase of " + str(tbRow['qty']) + " " + tbRow['symbol'] + " @ " + "${:<9.2f}".format(tbRow['price']);
    _logger.debug(note);
    cashRslt = plpy.execute(GD['get_cashSymbolAndCurrentPrice'], [tbRow['account_name']]);
    _logger.debug("got cash data: " + cashRslt[0]['symbol'] + " ${:<9.2f}".format(cashRslt[0]['price']));

    sellRslt = plpy.execute(GD['insert_trade_sell'], [tbRow['account_name'], tbRow['settlement_date'], tbRow['settlement_date'], tbRow['amount'] / cashRslt[0]['price'],
    cashRslt[0]['symbol'], cashRslt[0]['price'], 0.00, tbRow['amount'], const['SW_OUT'], note]);

    _logger.debug("tb done");
```

and here is the log output:

```
2018-04-02 14:27:11,933 [DEBUG   ] plpy.tba : {'sys_upd_user': 'dba', 'note': 'Buy', 'sys_updated_ts': '2018-04-02  14:27:11.930796-04', 'sys_created_ts': '2018-04-02 14:27:11.930445-04', 'symbol': 'BLV',
'adjusted_price': Decimal('88.6590'), 'price': Decimal('88.5600'), 'source_revenue_id': None, 'qty_left': Decimal('100.0000'), 'settlement_date': '2016-01-30', 'amount': Decimal('8860.95'),
'qty': Decimal('100.0000'), 'account_name': 'VG Savings', 'lot': 4, 'fees': Decimal('4.95'), 'source_sell_id': None, 'trade_date': '2016-01-28'}
2018-04-02 14:27:11,933 [DEBUG   ] plpy.tba : tb after: rev == None
2018-04-02 14:27:11,933 [DEBUG   ] plpy.tba : Sweep-Out for purchase of 100.0000 BLV @ $88.56    
2018-04-02 14:27:11,934 [DEBUG   ] plpy.tba : got cash data: VMFXX $1.00
```

The SQL in 'insert_trade_sell' executes fine from my IDE. Here it is:

```
insert_trade_sell = plpy.prepare("""
    INSERT INTO trade_sell_tbl (account_name, trade_date, settlement_date, qty, symbol, price, fees, amount, dest_of_funds, note)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)
    RETURNING sell_id
    """,
    ['text', 'date', 'date', 'numeric(9,4)', 'text', 'numeric(9,4)', 'numeric(9,2)', 'numeric(9,2)', 'text', 'text']
    );
```

Comment: Enable full statement logging in PG to see what's happening

Comment: eurotrash, I was able to pinpoint the location using full debugging for PG. Thx.

Comment: Nice one! //need more chars...